# The most frequent pattern of specific columns in Pandas.DataFrame in python

Tags: python, pandas

I know how to get the most frequent element of list of list, e.g.

```
a = [[3,4], [3,4],[3,4], [1,2], [1,2], [1,1],[1,3],[2,2],[3,2]]
print max(a, key=a.count)
```

should print `[3, 4]` even though the most frequent number is `1` for the first element and `2` for the second element.

**My question is** how to do the same kind of thing with Pandas.DataFrame.

For example, I'd like to know the implementation of the following method `get_max_freq_elem_of_df`:

```
def get_max_freq_elem_of_df(df):
  # do some things
  return freq_list

df = pd.DataFrame([[3,4], [3,4],[3,4], [1,2], [1,2], [1,1],[1,3],[2,2],[4,2]])
x = get_max_freq_elem_of_df(df)
print x # => should print [3,4]
```

Please notice that DataFrame.mode() method does not work. For above example, `df.mode()` returns `[1, 2]` not `[3,4]`

#### Update

have explained why DataFrame.mode() doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [find and select the most frequent data of column in pandas DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082671/find-and-select-the-most-frequent-data-of-column-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @Rafeh I believe it's not duplicate. I'd like to get the most frequent **pair** of number of **multiple** columns although the suggested question just for one column.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, mode calculates the mode for each column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `groupby.size` and then find the max:

```
>>> df.groupby([0,1]).size()
0  1
1  1    1
   2    2
   3    1
2  2    1
3  4    3
4  2    1
dtype: int64
>>> df.groupby([0,1]).size().idxmax()
(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

In python you'd use Counter*:

```
In [11]: from collections import Counter

In [12]: c = Counter(df.itertuples(index=False))

In [13]: c
Out[13]: Counter({(3, 4): 3, (1, 2): 2, (1, 3): 1, (2, 2): 1, (4, 2): 1, (1, 1): 1})

In [14]: c.most_common(1)  # get the top 1 most common items
Out[14]: [((3, 4), 3)]

In [15]: c.most_common(1)[0][0]  # get the item (rather than the (item, count) tuple)
Out[15]: (3, 4)
```

---

* Note that your solution

```
 max(a, key=a.count)
```

(although it works) is O(N^2), since on each iteration it needs to iterate through `a` (to get the count), whereas Counter is O(N).

Comment: DSMs is better as native pandas. Bit I'm leaving this here.