# How to find most common elemtent in a ndarray

Tags: python

I have a numpy array with the following shape `(11617, 37)`. The data is multi class data, and to establish a baseline, I need to find which class (or classes) are the most common.

I have tried [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/frequent-element-array/) formula and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297016/how-to-find-most-frequent-values-in-numpy-ndarray)

```
A = np.array([[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0],
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0],
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]])

axis = 0
u, indices = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)
answer = u[np.argmax(np.apply_along_axis(np.bincount, axis,                                              indices.reshape(arr.shape),
                                None, np.max(indices) + 1), axis=axis)]
```

**I need to find the most frequent combination of the 37 classes in my array**

Expected output:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
```

Comment: What were your finding when trying those two references?

Comment: Can you sample output as well?

Comment: one returned only zeroes, the other only ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the most frequent combination (`rows`, which means `axis=0`), you can try this!

```
A = np.array([[1,0,0,0],
             [1,0,0,1],
             [1,0,0,0]])

unique_rows,counts = np.unique(A, return_counts=True,axis=0)
unique_rows[np.argmax(counts)]
```

FYI, If the array you mentioned in the question is your target variable, then it is an example of multi-label data.

[This](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) may be of use for you to understand multi-class and multi-label

Answer (score 1):

You could try [np.unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_counts` parameter:

```
from operator import itemgetter

import numpy as np

A = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

uniques, counts = np.unique(A, axis=0, return_counts=True)

idxmax, _ = max(zip(range(len(counts)), counts), key=itemgetter(1))
print(uniques[idxmax])
```

**Output**

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter.most_common` if you convert your list of list elements to a `tuple` (convert the lists to tuples so they can be counted)

```
from collections import Counter

A = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

c = Counter(tuple(x) for x in A)
print(c.most_common()[0]) # ((0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 2)
```

This returns a `tuple` containing the most common list and the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

A really quick and easy solution:

```
A = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

print(max(A, key=A.count))
```

Which prints:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

If you need to pay attention to runtime or want to optimize your code - this is not the way you want to go. However, if you just need a quick solution, it might help to keep this one-liner in mind.

(`A.tolist()` gets you a list from a `np.ndarray` if you need that first.)

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
A = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
most_common = [Counter(i).most_common(1).pop()[0] for i in A]
most_common
   [0, 0, 0]
```