# Numpy: How to find the most frequent nonzero values in array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array of shape `(1,4,5)`,

```
arr = np.array([[[ 0,  0,  0,  3,  0],
                [ 0,  0,  2,  3,  2],
                [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
                [ 2,  1,  0,  0, 0]]])
```

And I would like to find the most frequent non-zero value in the array across a specific axis, and only returns zero if there are no other non-zero values.

Let's say I'm looking at axis=2, I would like to get something like `[[3,2,0,2]]` from this array (For the last row either 1 or 2 would be fine). Is there a good way to implement this?

I've tried the solution in this following question ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297016/how-to-find-most-frequent-values-in-numpy-ndarray)) , but I am unsure how to modify it so that it excludes a specific value.Thanks again!

Comment: Does your array include negative values as well? Could you also provide us with your desired output of above example for the case of axis=0 and axis=1?

Comment: I am currently working on simple non-negative integer array. I'm not so sure how the output should look like for axis=0, but axis=1 should look like `[[2, 1, 2, 3, 2]]` I think.

Comment: Is it that your array is always 3-D non-negative and you are only interested in axis=1 and 2? This will make a difference in what the best solution would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [numpy.apply_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) and a simple function to solve this. Here, we make use of [numpy.bincount](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to count the occurrences of numeric values and then [numpy.argmax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to get the highest occurrence. If there are no other values than `exclude`, we return it.

Code:

```
def get_freq(array, exclude):
    count = np.bincount(array[array != exclude])
    if count.size == 0:
        return exclude
    else:  
        return np.argmax(count) 

np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: get_freq(x, 0), axis=2, arr=arr)
```

Output:

```
array([[3, 2, 0, 1]])
```

Please note, that it will also return `exclude` if you pass an empty array.

**EDIT:**
As Ehsan noted, above solution will not work for negative values in the given array. For this case, use `Counter` from [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html):

```
arr = np.array([[[ 0,  -3,  0,  3,  0],
                 [ 0,  0,  2,  3,  2],
                 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
                 [ 2,  -5,  0,  -5, 0]]])

from collections import Counter

def get_freq(array, exclude):
    count = Counter(array[array != exclude]).most_common(1)
    if not count:
        return exclude
    else:  
        return count[0][0]
```

Output:

```
array([[-3,  2,  0, -5]])
```

`most_common(1)` returns the most occurring value in the `Counter` object as one element list with a tuple in which first element is the value, and second is its number of occurrences. This is returned as a list, thus the double indexing. If list is empty, then `most_common` has not found any occurrences (either only exclude or empty).

Comment: `np.bincount` is for non-negative arrays. This solution fails if array has negative values.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate solution (maybe not as efficient as the above one, but a unique one) -

```
#Gets the positions for the highest frequency numbers in axis=2
count_max_pos = np.argmax(np.sum(np.eye(5)[arr][:,:,:,1:], axis=2), axis=2)[0]+1

#gets the max values in based on the indices
k = enumerate(count_max_pos)
result = [arr[0][i] for i in k]

print(result)
```

```
[3,2,0,1]
```